# Using fadeIn() and fadeOut() to animate AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Upon fetching a result (it is simply a decimal) from a php file using ajax GET, I would like to fade out the old result and fade in a new one.

This is my current attempt to do this, but the problem is is that it will fade in and out occur every 30 seconds rather when there is a change in data.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  function update() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "balancefetch.php",             
    dataType: "html",            
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#response1").html(response); 
    }
 });
}
    setInterval(update, 30000);
    update();
    setInterval(fadein, 30000);
 $("#response1").fadeIn();
    setInterval(fadeout, 30000);
 $("#response1").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: check the value returned by your ajax to see if it is different than what is in `#response1`, no? You don't want to do the fades if it is the same. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Thomas, you are completely right, but I am clueless on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your success callback to

```
success: function(response){    
  if ($("#response1").html() != response) {
    $("#response1").fadeOut(200, function() {
      $("#response1").html(response); 
      $("#response1").fadeIn();
    });
  }
}
```

and just have

```
setInterval(update, 30000);
update();
```

Comment: This fades out the text every response, but not when the output is different. Would you know how to only do this fade when the new query returns a result different to what was previously in place?

Comment: You mean it doesn't fade when the output is the same? add `if (response != $("#response1").html())` in success callback

Comment: Don't know why, but it just keeps refreshing every 30 seconds even if there  is no change. The php file echos a decimal and that's it. Here is the full code if you don't mind having a look. http://pastebin.com/9vFk3PCJ

Comment: What are the values of `$("#response1").html()` and `response` make sure they're equal.

Comment: So at the moment the php script executes and returns 0.28  . And the html  where the update is pointed is <span id="response1" style="display: inline;">    
0.28</span>